# Is there anyway to put Existing Text in Math Mode with Texmaker

Tags: math-mode, windows, texmaker, keyboard

There is provision to make existing text bold by simply selecting the text and pressing `CTRL+B`.
There is a keyboard shortcut of `CTRL+ALT+M`, but instead of putting existing content in Math  mode, it erases the highlighted content and creates a place holder for the writing contents in Math mode.

I was wondering, does a keyboard shortcut exist to achieve what I want?

Comment: Sadly No AFAIK.

Comment: I guess this can be request item for TexMaker. However, I am wondering why they made the shortcut for Math mode in this manner?

Comment: I agree, this sounds like a reasonable feature request. Other commands, e.g. bold or italic, already work like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid the answer is **NO**. All math (except math fonts like `\mathit` etc) shortcuts do not recognize *selection*. Hence you can't select something and put it in math mode, at present.

You can see those shortcuts by going to `Options` --> `Configure Texmaker` to get

[image]

Click on the `shortcuts` button at the left end to see all the shortcuts (assigned and to be assigned). You can clearly see that all text and math text shortcuts can be used with selection but not math mode shortcuts.

[image]

[image]

This may be a feature request for texmaker IMO.